# Run-time error '1004'. Excel cannot access 'Downloads'. The document may be read-only or encrypted

Tags: excel, vba, permissions, runtime-error

I'm trying to run some code in VBA, but I reach this error. The code was working until yesterday, I'm not sure what changed that could cause the error.

```
    Dim pathName, Filename As String
    Dim Z As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Z = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("C5").Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Z, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True)

    '''''''''

    wb.Save
    wb.Close
```

The debug prompt highlights the 
`Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Z, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True)` line.
I am trying to access another Excel workbook. The path Z is valid.
Do you have any idea what might be causing this issue?

Thank you,
Filippo

Comment: Assuming the value in `z` is valid: Can you open this file manually in Excel (not using VBA)?

Comment: Does [THIS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-document-may-be-read-only-or-encrypted/f35b11c7-4831-42d2-9b77-f74197208e76) help?

Comment: Has the value in `C5` changed? i.e. now pointing to **SharePoint**

Comment: @FunThomas yes I can open the files manually

Comment: @SiddharthRout no, unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: @Zac the default path is C:\username\Downloads\file.xlsx - I've tried to move the file in other folders (including some on Sharepoint) but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the path to your file is **C:\username\Downloads\**? That path seems a bit odd. Generally you will have **C:\Users\username\Downloads\**

Comment: @Zac yes it's what you're saying, sorry I missed one User in the comment